# openvpn --config conf.ovpn results in 'RTNETLINK answers: File exists'

Tags: kali-linux, openvpn

I'm trying to configure a vpn client (first and only for this server).
The server is running on a Raspberry 3 Pi configured with PiVPN, that generated the client config file too.

Here is the output of `openvpn --config conf.ovpn`:

```
Tue Jun 27 21:35:42 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.0 i686-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 22 2017
Tue Jun 27 21:35:42 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.08
Enter Private Key Password: *************
Tue Jun 27 21:35:45 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]2.x.x.x:1194
Tue Jun 27 21:35:45 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue Jun 27 21:35:45 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]2.x.x.x:1194
Tue Jun 27 21:35:46 2017 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]2.x.x.x:1194
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.3/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external  program exited with error status: 2
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

On client side:

```
root@kali:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:75:08:fa:3b:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:55:f9:79:b5:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.64/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 2511sec preferred_lft 2511sec
    inet6 2001:b07:2e0:81c6:7341:e6d7:dab4:9e57/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 25114sec preferred_lft 10714sec
    inet6 fe80::de7a:3e8b:1eb4:4163/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On server side:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:70:cf:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.67/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:b07:2e0:81c6:4efb:fa6b:69b7:a22b/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 24935sec preferred_lft 10535sec
    inet6 fe80::4137:8750:ed76:79cf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:25:9a:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8d7:6c11:f28e:eea0/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1c6c:2047:3987:5469/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

EDIT:

Content of conf.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 2.x.x.x 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 1
auth-nocache
```

Content of server.conf:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.69.80"
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.70.40"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 1
```

Comment: `ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external  program exited with error status: 2` You dont have `iputils2` installed or you are not running openvpn as root user...

Comment: `root@kali:~# ip -V` outputs `ip utility, iproute2-ss161212`

Comment: Then you are adding a route that is already set by openvpn internals. Can you post you `conf.ovpn` and your server conf? If your server is pushing a route like `push "route 10.8.0.3 255.255.255.255"` or something inside `10.8.0.0` it will fail, cause those addresses are already configured(and it's respective routes) when ip is being set if the mask is `/24`...

Comment: There is no need to route something that is already on the same "Lan" after the tunnel is up. Your client is failing to get that route running cause it already exists then...

Comment: Config files are now in the main question.

Comment: So, if I've got it right, there is no need for the first "push"...right? When they are needed instead? Just to understand

Comment: just comment the `push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"` and `push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"`...

Comment: Ill put my comments as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at your logs:

```
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.3/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Tue Jun 27 21:35:47 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external  program exited with error status: 2
```

This specific snippet of log is saying that you are trying to create a route that already exists(`RTNETLINK answers: File exists`). When you define the ip addresses at server and client(or the pool that the clients will use), the routes used to communicate between those ips are created on demand based on that "LAN" netmask. This lines at the server configuration:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
```

With this in mind, you don't need to force route push to ip addresses at the same network with masks `/32` or `/24`. You just need to delete or comment the following lines at your server configuration file:

```
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Now, there will not be more repeated routes :)